# Concatenate in sql server query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I try to concatenate id and date to populate in dropdown.

```
select VisitID as Value,  Convert(nvarchar(50),VisitID)+' - '+Convert(nvarchar(50),VisitDate) as Text 
from Visit
```

above query work for me to concatenate
but the result is in the form of '21 - Feb 13 2013 12:00AM'

i want the result should be in form of '21 - 02/13/2012'

what I need to do?

Comment: what do you mean with 'not working'? error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and supply third parameter for date and time styles.

Try this:

```
select VisitID as Value, Convert(nvarchar(50),VisitID)+' - '+Convert(nvarchar(50),VisitDate, 101) as Text 
from Visit
```

Comment: +1 Better to specify the time style than to simply limit the characters

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
SELECT 
 VisitID AS Value, 
 CONVERT(VARCHAR, VisitID, 20) + '-' + ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, VisitDate, 20), '') AS Text 
FROM Visit
```

Comment: It is better to specify the time style than to simply limit the characters as you have more control over what's happening...especially when server dates differ from clients, see answer by Iswanto San

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
visitid [Value]
,(CAST(VisitID AS VARCHAR) + '-' _ CAST(VisitDate AS VARCHAR)) [Text]
FROM Visit
```